# Part of my template or html disappears. Creating a module for Prestashop 1.7.6.1, php 7.1.9

Tags: php, css, templates, smarty, prestashop-1.7

For reason that I don't understand one div tag and a class disappear from my code in the home.tpl file. The module is called upload_data and it is organized in the folders like this:
[image that shows the arrangement of folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO0SZ.png)

Here's my code

upload_data.php

```
<?php
class Upload_data extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'upload_data';
        $this->author = 'Luis Sorto';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();
        $this->displayName=$this->l('Upload CSV Files');
        $this->description=$this->l('This is a test module to upload csv files');
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.7.0.0', 'max' => '1.7.99.99');
    }
    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('displayHome');
    }
    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }
    public function hookDisplayHome()
    {
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/home.tpl');
    }
    public function hookHeader()
    {
        $this->context->controller->addCSS(array(
            $this->_path.'views/css/upload_data.css'
        ));
        $this->context->controller->addJS(array(
            $this->_path.'views/js/upload_data.js'
        ));
    }
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/admin/configure.tpl');
    }
}
?>
```

home.tpl

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x350" class="upload_data-img"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

upload_data.css

```
.upload_data-img{width:100%;}
```

When I load the page in my localhoast using xampp this is what I get when inspect the code

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1920x350">
</div>
```

I tried edditing the html with the google chrome tool, and if I add the div and the class it works perfectly. How ever and obviously when I refresh the page this change won't be there.

I've tried changing the location of the css file and copying it everywhere and it didn't work for me. Also tried changing the tag class for className. Hope this is not a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop has a build-in mobile device detector and you can hide some modules for mobile in modules settings, so you can check that (because Chrome with dev tools open i considered a mobile device).

[image]

Comment: I think the problem has something to do with the cache. Not sure if php or apache or my browser. I already change some things in my php.ini like 
opcache.enable=0
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
but this doesn't change the problem